# Data modeling with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, database, nosql

I'm having trouble getting Cassandra's way of modeling data, mainly because this is my first time using a non-relational database. I'm not sure about how to make my model right now. Basically my model consists of Galaxies, Stars, Nebulas, Planets and Moons. A galaxy can have all of those, so it'd be an N:M relation. From what I understand, the idea would be to make a single table with all those components, or at least that's how I understood Cassandra's data modeling strategy and the idea of denormalizing.

It doesn't seem right to me though, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Deciding on the right data model for your database doesn't only depends on WHAT you're going to have in your DB, but very much on HOW you're going to use it - what your INSERTs and SELECTs would look like, how many of them you'll have, what will be the ratio between them, and so on.

There's a very good online course regarding C* data modeling you may find interesting: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at this, would be in terms of the relationships of the entities you are trying to model.  For instance, galaxies have stars, stars have planets, planets have moons; and they all have certain characteristics (orbital period in days, radius in km).  You could model that similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE galaxyobjects (
  galaxy text,
  star text,
  planet text,
  moon text,
  spectralclass text,
  radiuskm double,
  orbitalperioddays double,
  PRIMARY KEY ((galaxy, star), planet, moon)
);
```

Of course, spectral class would really only apply to the `star` column, but in a denormalized model you would see it on every row.

After inserting some data, my table may look like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM galaxyobjects;

 galaxy    | star       | planet      | moon   | orbitalperioddays | radiuskm | spectralclass
-----------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+----------+---------------
 Milky Way | Kepler-186 | Kepler-186f |    n/a |          129.9459 |     7072 |            M1
 Milky Way |        Sun |       Earth |   Moon |              27.3 |   3474.8 |            G2
 Milky Way |        Sun |       Earth |    n/a |           365.256 |     6371 |            G2
 Milky Way |        Sun |     Jupiter | Europa |             3.551 |   1560.8 |            G2
 Milky Way |        Sun |     Jupiter |     Io |              1.77 |   1821.6 |            G2
 Milky Way |        Sun |     Jupiter |    n/a |           4332.59 |    71492 |            G2

(6 rows)
```

Now, if I wanted to query for Jupiter and its moons:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM galaxyobjects 
    WHERE galaxy='Milky Way' AND star='Sun' and planet='Jupiter';

 galaxy    | star | planet  | moon   | orbitalperioddays | radiuskm | spectralclass
-----------+------+---------+--------+-------------------+----------+---------------
 Milky Way |  Sun | Jupiter | Europa |             3.551 |   1560.8 |            G2
 Milky Way |  Sun | Jupiter |     Io |              1.77 |   1821.6 |            G2
 Milky Way |  Sun | Jupiter |    n/a |           4332.59 |    71492 |            G2

(3 rows)
```

Notes:

- I designated `galaxy` and `star` as partition keys.  As Cassandra has a max of 2 billion columns per partition, and a galaxy can definitely have billions of objects orbiting inside it, I thought that additionally partitioning by `star` would be necessary.  Note that in this model, you must designate both a `galaxy` and a `star` in each query.
- I suppose you could extend the partition key to include `planet`, but then you wouldn't be able to query a `star` for its planets.
- In this model, `planet` and `moon` are clustering keys, so they are not required to be specified on each query.  However you cannot skip them, so you would not be able specify (in your WHERE clause) a `moon` without also specifying a `planet`.
- My data modeling senses don't really like using `n/a` as a clustering key when querying a planet on its own (without a moon).  So perhaps there's a better way to model that.  Maybe a collection of moons would be more appropriate?